# Detection of 2d collision side behaving weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, mesh-collider

I am making a basic Breakout game and using the following code to detect if the collision between the Capsule Collider 2d and circle collider 2d has happened on the top:

```
bool FindIfTopCol(Collision2D other)
{
    print("collider.y " + collidersize.y / 2);
    ContactPoint2D[] contacts = other.contacts;
    if (contacts[0].point.y - transform.position.y > collidersize.y / 2)
    {
        print("top " + (contacts[0].point.y - transform.position.y));
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        print("not top " + (contacts[0].point.y - transform.position.y));
        return false;
    }
}
```

For the most part the detection was working fine but after running the game a while and especially after the circle collider gets into a non top collision, the method seems to return all the collisions as non top collision.

To figure out the issue i placed print statements and this is the result:

collidery 0.2610874
top 0.2885695

collidery 0.2610874
not top 0.2552783 **First actual non top collision**

collidery 0.2610874
not top 0.2542975 **It's a top collision, but shows as not top**

collidery 0.2610874
not top 0.2558844 **It's top collision, but shows as not top**

And the rest of the collisions for the session is also wrong like this, until i restart the game.

I am not sure whats going wrong here.

And also if there is a better way to detect collision side, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what's happening here but I would use [`OnCollisionEnter2D()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) event to detect collisions. Then compare the contact point with the collider center to figure out what surface it hit. Here's an example from [kacyesp](https://answers.unity.com/users/403101/kacyesp.html).

```
Vector3 contactPoint = collision.contacts[0].point;
Vector3 center = collider.bounds.center;

bool right = contactPoint.x > center.x;
bool top = contactPoint.y > center.y;
```